# Tkinter buttons won't work. KeyError: '!button3'

Tags: python, function, tkinter, button, keyerror

When I try to run a bit of code inside a function in my my script using tkinter, the buttons won't show up and I get a KeyError. But, when I run the piece of code separately in another python file, it works just fine.

This is the code that I ran separately and worked:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkmacosx import Button

bgfarge = 'gray15'
fgfarge = 'white'

editor = Tk()
editor.title('Edit')
editor.configure(bg=bgfarge)

global username_verify
global password_verify

username_verify = StringVar()
password_verify = StringVar()

global username_login_entry
global password_login_entry


Label(editor, text="Passord:", bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge).grid(row=0, sticky=E)
username_login_entry = Entry(editor, textvariable=username_verify, show='*', bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge, highlightbackground=bgfarge, highlightcolor=bgfarge, width=10)
username_login_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
Label(editor, text="Nøkkel:", bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge).grid(row=1, sticky=E)
password_login_entry = Entry(editor, textvariable=password_verify, show='*', bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge, highlightbackground=bgfarge, highlightcolor=bgfarge, width=10)
password_login_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)
Button(editor, text="Login", width=60, height=20, borderless=1).grid(columnspan=2, row=2, sticky=W, padx=15, pady=7)
Button(editor, text="Quit", width=60, height=20, borderless=1).grid(columnspan=2, row=2, sticky=E, padx=15, pady=7)

editor.bind('<Return>')

editor.mainloop()
```

And this is the code I run inside a function in my script:

```
def Edit():
    global editor
    global open_big
    global open_small

    bgfarge = 'gray15'
    fgfarge = 'white'

    editor = Tk()
    editor.title('Edit')
    editor.configure(bg=bgfarge)


    global username_verify
    global password_verify

    username_verify = StringVar()
    password_verify = StringVar()

    global username_login_entry
    global password_login_entry


    Label(editor, text="Passord:", bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge).grid(row=0, sticky=E)
    username_login_entry = Entry(editor, textvariable=username_verify, show='*', bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge, highlightbackground=bgfarge, highlightcolor=bgfarge, width=10)
    username_login_entry.grid(column=1, row=0)
    Label(editor, text="Nøkkel:", bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge).grid(row=1, sticky=E)
    password_login_entry = Entry(editor, textvariable=password_verify, show='*', bg=bgfarge, fg=fgfarge, highlightbackground=bgfarge, highlightcolor=bgfarge, width=10)
    password_login_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    Button(editor, text="Login", width=60, height=20, command=login_verify, borderless=1).grid(columnspan=2, row=2, sticky=W, padx=15, pady=7)
    Button(editor, text="Quit", width=60, height=20, command=on_closing_edit, borderless=1).grid(columnspan=2, row=2, sticky=E, padx=15, pady=7)

    editor.bind('<Return>', login_verify)

    editor.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing_edit)
    editor.mainloop()
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1885, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 1103, in cmd
    self.cnf['command']() if self.cnf.get('command') else None
  File "/Users/Kristoffer/Desktop/Pycharm prosjekter/KeyPass/KeyPass.py", line 877, in Edit
    Button(editor, text="Login", width=60, height=20, command=login_verify, borderless=1).grid(columnspan=2, row=2, sticky=W, padx=15, pady=7)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/widget.py", line 90, in __init__
    tkb.ButtonBase.__init__(self, 'normal', master, cnf, **kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self._configure1(self.cnf)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 947, in _configure1
    self._set_configure(self._get_options(opt, kw))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 823, in _get_options
    if self._mouse_state_condition() and self.cnf.get('overbackground'):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tkmacosx/basewidget.py", line 369, in _mouse_state_condition
    con2 = bool(self.winfo_containing(*self.winfo_pointerxy()) == self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1066, in winfo_containing
    return self._nametowidget(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1500, in nametowidget
    w = w.children[n]
KeyError: '!button3'
```

Comment: why two `mainloop`?

Comment: share some part of your code that only needs copy paste to reproduce the error please

Comment: It doesn't have to do with script in a function or not. Can you please share the function `login_verify()`.

Comment: I figured out a workaround! Tbh I can't really remember what the solution was, since I am very new to this and I have solved a lot of problems in the code since this problem. But thank you anyways!